# Consulta con un buscador en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

queria saber si esta bien hecha la consulta Where para buscar los posts de un blog que contengan una palabra "query":

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
      //guarda la palabra en $query

      $query = $request->input('query');

      //consulta si "$query" se encuentra dentro del contenido de algun mensaje

      $messages = Message::with('user')->where('content','LIKE',"%query%")->get();

      //retorna la vista "welcome.blade.php" con los resultados

      return view('welcome', [

        'messages' => $messages,

      ]);

    }
```

no me devuelve ningun post, pero tengo 2 con esa palabra.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente debes concatenar los caracteres de porcentaje (%) a la variable $query, como en cualquier cadena de texto de PHP:

```
$messages = Message::with('user')->where('content','LIKE','%' . $query . '%')->get();
```

Comment: Como consejo extra, añadele un trim() a $query

Comment: No es necesario, el middleware TrimStrings lo hace y normalmente es ejecutado en cada request.

Comment: Ese middleware esta activo solo en versiones superiores a 5.4

Comment: 5.4 y superiores, además 5.5 es LTS.

Comment: Si, y por eso mismo como solo pone 5.* es recomendable por lo menos explicarlo, por si usa 5.1 u otras